# Calling Oracle PL/SQL stored procedure form ODI

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle-data-integrator

I am going to call a PL SQL stored procedure from ODI which I have created it before. To achieve this matter, by performing a thorough search on this subject on the Internet, I have found that I am supposed to do the following steps:

1. Create a ODI procedure.
2. Put code
   `begin schema.myproc(with param) end;` in a task of that.
3. Add this created procedure to an ODI package and run.

So, it is:

```
begin 
my_schema.procedure_name(20200701)
end;
```

Now, after doing all above steps, the below error is occurred by which I have got confused what to do, as I have been unable to find a solution.

```
ODI-1228: Task Procedure-test-task1 fails on the target connection PHY_PARSDB.
Caused By: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 3, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:
:= . ( % ;
```

So, can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot a `;`

Correct code is:

```
begin 
my_schema.procedure_name(20200701);
end;
```

Comment: can you help me with passing parameter to the mentioned procedure in the above block code? I mean, I am going to have a variable named date_key, initialize it, then use it instead of available constant(20200701).

Comment: Sorry I'm not an ODI expert, maybe you'll find your answer in the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01//integrate.1111/e12643/procedures.htm#ODIDG405.

Comment: `#<PROJECT_CODE>.date_key` if it's a project variable or `#GLOBAL.date_key` if it's a global variable. If you need more details, please create a new question so future reader can also get the answer.